# Canonot get bootstrap working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get bootstrap working with rails, but so far without luck. I am following the setup instructions on this website: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

**Here is what the friendly terminal says:**

```
Toms-MacBook-Air:GetItDone tomfinet$ bin/rails server
/Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION (NameError)
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/tomfinet/Documents/Rails Development/Projects/GetItDone/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomfinet/Documents/Rails Development/Projects/GetItDone/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/tomfinet/Documents/Rails Development/Projects/GetItDone/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tomfinet/Documents/Rails Development/Projects/GetItDone/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/tomfinet/Documents/Rails Development/Projects/GetItDone/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Users/tomfinet/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**Here is my Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem "capybara-email", "~> 2.2.0"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.4.0'
end
```

**Here is my application.scss file:**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
@import "bootstrap";

div.alert {
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.flash.success { border: 2px solid green; color: green; }
div.flash.error   { border: 2px solid red;   color: red;   }
div.flash.notice  { border: 2px solid blue;  color: blue;  }

.clear { clear: both; }

div.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

div.nav h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

div.nav a { text-decoration: none !important; }

div.nav ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  clear: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

div.nav ul li {
  float: right;
}

div.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
}

div.nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #eee;
}
```

**Here is my application.js file:**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

So what's the fuss? I've ran bundle install after adding the gems to the gemfile (successfully).

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: have you installed the sprockets gem? If not: add `sprockets-rails` to your gemfile and bundle again.

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Nope it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/131) with an older version of the sprockets gem.

I advise to add following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sprockets-rails'
```

Then run `bundle update sprockets-rails` and ensure in your `Gemfile.lock` that it installed at least a `2.2` version of `sprockets`.

Answer (score 1):

Just some browsing shows that the error was caused by [`sprockets`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails) not having a particular version reference in an earlier release:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/131

You should definitely update your `Gemfile` to include the latest `sprockets,` as well as any other gem which might be out of date:

```
#Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5' #-> Bumped the version
gem 'sprockets-rails' #-> this will add the latest version

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem "capybara-email", "~> 2.2.0"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.4.0'
end
```

After that, just run `bundle install` and then `bundle update` -- it should resolve.